# A subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$.
Suppose $H=A\times B$.

> Does it follow that $H\cap K=(A\cap K)\times (B\cap K)$?

I'm having a hard time trying to prove that $H\cap K\le (A\cap K).(B\cap K)$.

Thanks, Robert.

EDIT: The question stated in this form has negative answer. 
I should have added the assumption that $A\cap K$ in non-trivial!

Comment: Why not try and think of a small counterexample?

Comment: There are counterexamples using vector spaces and subspaces, for example, which you can even draw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$Say $H = \Z/4\Z \times \Z/2\Z$. Let $K$ be the subgroup of this generated by $(1, 1)$, i.e.
$$
K = \{(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1), (0, 0)\}.
$$
Then $K \cap (\Z/4\Z \times \{0\}$) is a cyclic group of order $2$, but the desired statement clearly fails here.

Comment: Shame on me! Thanks. Is there a simple example with $A\cap K$ non-trivial? This is actually the situation I have.

Comment: @Robert I'll think about it. Will remove this, in the meantime.

Comment: @Robert There, I think this works.

Comment: It does! Thanks.